# How can I decouple this JavaScript code further?

Tags: javascript, jquery, decoupling

I have a JavaScript object. And you can see the line:

```
window.gv.borderiseTDCell(this);
```

Is tigthly coupled to the window (if `gv` is not initialised it crashes). However what I really want is to be able to do is:

```
//bind the click event
jQuery('.highlightableTDCell').click(function () {

    borderiseTDCell(this);
});
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas what I can do? This is the full lisinng (with tight coupling):

```
gridview = function () {

    //bind the click event
    jQuery('.highlightableTDCell').click(function () {

        window.gv.borderiseTDCell(this);
    });

};


//selecting cell
gridview.prototype.selectCell = function (obj) {

       //dostuff to cell

    };
```

And a page...

```
<table class="EditTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">     
      <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="">0</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="">0 akudsfsa fdhsad fiasgdf swae</div>
            </td>
            <td class="highlightableTDCell">
                <div>
                    <input value="0.00"/>
                </div>
            </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you are using JQuery, use $this instead of this, so you can access the correct pointer...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using `this` when you should be using `$(this)`

```
borderiseTDCell($(this));
```

Also, `gridview` doesn't seem to be defined:

```
var gridview = function (){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd need a library to outline a table cell. How about creating a class called `outlinedCell`

```
.outlinedCell{border:1px solid #f00;}
```

Then you can add, remove, or toggle this class

```
//bind the click event
$('.highlightableTDCell').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('outlinedCell');
    // or // $(this).removeClass('outlinedCell');
    // or // $(this).toggleClass('outlinedCell');
});
```

**LIVE SAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/WJp2Z/**

Comment: appreciate the response but it does't really answer my question. This class will do more than just highlight cells. thanks